# HorizontalPodAutoscaler scaleDown behavior

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, hpa, horizontalpodautoscaler

We are using **v1.18** and **ArgoCD**.

**Desired Behavior**: scale down by 1 pod at a time every 5 minutes when usage under 50%

The HPA scales up and down perfectly using default spec.

When we add the custom behavior to spec to achieve **Desired Behavior**, we do not see scaleDown happening at all.

I'm guessing that our configuration is in conflict with the algorithm and that this message may be a clue:

```
recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest recent recommendation
```

**EDIT**: We got it working with the custom configured behavior with other settings such as 5 pods per 10 min.  I've also noticed that in a policy **value** can be spread out across **periodSeconds**, meaning if my **periodSeconds** is 600 and **value** is 5, I can scale down 1 pod, then down 2 pods 120seconds later, and down 2 pods again 120seconds later, all within those 600 seconds whereas I had previously read that there will be exactly **ONE** scaling event of up to **value** number of pods per **periodSeconds**.  Anyways, we are still trying to figure out how to scale down by 1 pod per 5 minutes.  My theory is that if my current CPU avg is 49% with 10 pods, and I only allow scaling down by 1 pod at a time, we will end up with >50%(target) usage, so the "desired" pods stays the same.

**HPA DEF**

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: stackoverflow
  labels:
    app: question
  namespace: HPA
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: scaleTarget/v1alpha1
    kind: Rollout
    name: scaleTarget
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 15
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
  behavior:
    scaleDown:
      stabilizationWindowSeconds: 300
      policies:
      - type: Pods
        value: 1
        periodSeconds: 300
      selectPolicy: Min
```

**DESCRIBE HPA**

```
Name:                                                  my-app
Namespace:                                             default
Labels:                                                app=my-app
                                                       app.kubernetes.io/instance=my-app
Annotations:                                           kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                                                         {"apiVersion":"autoscaling/v2beta2","kind":"HorizontalPodAutoscaler","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"my-app","app.kubernete...
CreationTimestamp:                                     Wed, 20 Jan 2021 14:17:29 -0800
Reference:                                             Rollout/my-app
Metrics:                                               ( current / target )
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  10% (10m) / 50%
Min replicas:                                          2
Max replicas:                                          15
Rollout pods:                                          15 current / 15 desired
Conditions:
  Type            Status  Reason               Message
  ----            ------  ------               -------
  AbleToScale     True    ScaleDownStabilized  recent recommendations were higher than current one, applying the highest recent recommendation
  ScalingActive   True    ValidMetricFound     the HPA was able to successfully calculate a replica count from cpu resource utilization (percentage of request)
  ScalingLimited  True    ScaleDownLimit       the desired replica count is decreasing faster than the maximum scale rate
Events:
  Type    Reason             Age                   From                       Message
  ----    ------             ----                  ----                       -------
 Normal  SuccessfulRescale  50m (x71 over 42h)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  (combined from similar events): New size: 15; reason: cpu resource utilization (percentage of request) above target
```

Comment: I tried replicating it and I see the same issue. I was able to downscale setting `selectPolicy: Max` so you may want to try that and let me know it it solves it. I'm not sure why this solved it for me but I will try to learn more about how this works and let you know if I come up with an explaination.